# Copy text out of a pdf file shown in pdf viewer in Chrome web browser

Tags: google-chrome

I open a pdf file in Chrome webbrowser. I can't copy some text out of the pdf file by selecting and Ctrl-c. How shall I do then? Thanks.

For example, opening up this link in chrome https://www.kevinsheppard.com/images/0/09/Python_introduction.pdf

I get two different results on page 1. The first one doesn't show "copy" after selection and right click, while the second does. I think maybe I don't use it correctly?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is this all PDFs or just some? Maybe the PDF has been "secured" - Restricted documents are often protected against copying. If you can’t highlight or copy any text, then the document has been restricted.

Comment: all pdf files....

Comment: [Copy and Paste from a PDF in Chrome - the SOLUTION](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/rWjpnswXLec)

Comment: The solution seems to use adobe reader, which I don't want to have on Ubuntu. Update my post.

Comment: Works fine here (Windows 7 64 bit, latest chrome). Confirmed pdf is not protected. Can copy as expected.

Comment: It works fine for me with Chromium / Ubuntu. I have not made any configuration changes, though I do have a selection of plug-ins installed.

Comment: @AFH: I get inconsistent results in the pictures.

Comment: I get the first context menu when nothing is selected and the second when text is selected. I can't reproduce your screen with the first context menu, and text apparently selected. I have tried it with your link and selected precisely the same text, but I always get the second context menu.

Answer (score 6):

By appending the URL to the Google Drive Viewer service -

```
https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url=https://www.kevinsheppard.com/images/0/09/Python_introduction.pdf
```

..I was able to view the PDF & copy text from that file

Comment: Does the job! Great, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit of a kludge, but on Windows, I'm able to copy text from the Print Preview window, even though I cannot from the Chrome tab.

Comment: Nice solution!!

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't Ctrl+C because a) it's copy protected, and/or b) is a picture of some text and not actual (selectable) text.

Take a screen-shot of it, feed it through some OCR solution ([example service](http://www.onlineocr.net/)), copy text and correct anything the OCR didn't recognize properly.

Comment: happens to all pdf files.

Comment: See my update...

Answer (score 0):

If the PDF is not copy protected then the problem you are facing is due to a bug in the Chrome PDF reader. The solution is to first left click anywhere on the page of the PDF with the mouse before selecting text or pressing CTRL + A and CTRL + C to copy the text.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Chrome PDF viewer. But the PDF viewer from **Firefox** allowed me the copy operation.

- ❌ Chrome
- ❌ Edge
- ❌ Adobe Reader
- ✔️ Firefox

PDF files can have security restrictions which includes "copy protection".

[image: PDF Document Restrictions]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer from @h3xStream, while using [PEX 8311AA Data Book](https://docs.broadcom.com/doc/pex8311-detailed-technical-spec-data_Book-V1Dec2009) and trying to copy text:

- ❌ Edge 111.0.1661.62 under Windows 11
- ❌ Adobe Acrobat Reader 2023.001.20064 under Windows 11
- ❌ Chrome 112.0.5615.49 under Ubuntu 18.04
- ✔️ FireFox 111.0.1 under Ubuntu 18.04
- ✔️ Evince (Document Viewer) 3.28.4 under Ubuntu 18.04

Adobe Acrobat Reader was the only tool which showed *Content Copying* was Not Allowed in the document properties:

[image]